# What is the explanation for &:hex in ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex, loops, hash, hex

I am trying to figure out what &:hex mean in this code

```
    sort_by{|x|x.scan(/\d*/).map &:hex}
```

The full code looks like this

```
 class Array
  def version_sort
   sort_by{|x|x.scan(/\d*/).map &:hex}
  end
 end
```

I know that map does an action to the scanned part , so I am guessing it replaces numbers

```
 (/\d*/)
```

with

```
&:hex
```

but I dont know what that means

Comment: Did you search like this? http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bruby%5D+%22%26%3A%22

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case `&` takes an object and if the object is not already a [`Proc`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Proc.html), as it is the case with the Symbol `:hex` it will try to invoke the method `to_proc` on it. In the [Symbol](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/Symbol.html#method-i-to_proc) documentation you will find the implementation detail for the `to_proc` method:

> > **to_proc**
> >
> > Returns a Proc object which respond to the given method by sym.
> >
> > ```
> > (1..3).collect(&:to_s)  #=> ["1", "2", "3"]
> > ```

In your case through `&:hex` the symbol `:hex` will be converted into the Proc object which is equivalent to `{ |item| item.hex() }`

What is a Proc exactly? Basically the Proc class is a basic anonymous function. In Ruby the notion of a *callable object* is embodied in Ruby through objects to which you can send the message `call`. The main representatives of these kind are `Proc` and `Lambda`.

Proc objects are self-contained code sequences, that can be created, stored, passed around as method arguments and executed at some point through `call`. A method like `map` can also take a block as an argument which is the case if you pass `&:hex`.

In the method definition of `map` a kind of implicit call to `Proc.new` is made using the very same block. Then the Proc is executed through its call method executing the code embodied by the Proc object.

Answer (score 1):

These two expressions are equivalent:

```
foo.map {|x| x.hex}
foo.map &:hex
```

Comment: Hey thanks, can you provide a documentations for it or a reading. I want to learn more about &:hex and is there a library of these type of shortcuts/expresions?

Comment: @bolonomicz the link I have provided has 33 topics... go through those..